# If $\lim{a_n} = 0$ , and $0 \leq {b_n} \leq {a_n}$, prove $\lim{b_n} = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

so far I have:

We must show that if $b_n$ converges then for all $\epsilon \leq 0$, there is some $N \in \mathbb N$  such that for all $n > N$, $|{b_n}-0| \leq \epsilon$.
This can be written as ${b_n} - \epsilon < 0 < {b_n} + \epsilon$.

We know ${a_n}$ converges to 0, so ${a_n} - \epsilon < 0 < {a_n} + \epsilon$.

Since ${b_n} \leq {a_n}$ then ${b_n} - \epsilon < {a_n} - \epsilon < {b_n} + \epsilon < {a_n} + \epsilon$.

This implies ${b_n} - \epsilon < {a_n} - \epsilon < 0 < {b_n} + \epsilon < {a_n} + \epsilon$,

hence ${b_n} - \epsilon <  0 < {b_n} + \epsilon$,which can be written as
$|{b_n}-0| \leq \epsilon$, as required.

I'm not sure if this is valid proof or not, and what I'd have to add.

Comment: What have you tried? This site is not for solving your homework.

Answer (score 1):

so far I have:

We must show that if $b_n$ converges then for all $\epsilon \leq 0$, there is some $N \in \mathbb N$  such that for all $n > N$, $|{b_n}-0| \leq \epsilon$.
This can be written as ${b_n} - \epsilon < 0 < {b_n} + \epsilon$.

We know ${a_n}$ converges to 0, so ${a_n} - \epsilon < 0 < {a_n} + \epsilon$.

Since ${b_n} \leq {a_n}$ then ${b_n} - \epsilon < {a_n} - \epsilon < {b_n} + \epsilon < {a_n} + \epsilon$.

This implies ${b_n} - \epsilon < {a_n} - \epsilon < 0 < {b_n} + \epsilon < {a_n} + \epsilon$,

hence ${b_n} - \epsilon <  0 < {b_n} + \epsilon$,which can be written as
$|{b_n}-0| \leq \epsilon$, as required.

I'm not sure if this is valid proof or not, and what I'd have to add.

Comment: You may just say that $|b_n-0|=|b_n|=b_n \leq a_n \leq |a_n| =|a_n-0|<\varepsilon$ for $n>N$.

Comment: You got your inequalities wrong. If $b_n < a_n$ then also $b_n +\varepsilon < a_n + \varepsilon$, and this is actually what you need.

Comment: Yes, just realised that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $\epsilon$ be given.

There is a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|a_n|<\epsilon$.

We have

$0\le b_n \le a_n <\epsilon$.

Hence?